# Linq to SQL GROUP and SUM

Tags: linq-to-sql, group-by, sum

I have this linq to sql working (after help from this group)

```
var resultTotal = (from fuf in db.fad_userFoods
              join fu in db.fad_user on fuf.userID equals fu.userID
              join ff in db.fad_food on fuf.foodID equals ff.foodID 
              where fuf.userID == thisGuid && fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
              group fuf.userID by new {fu.dateJoined} into g
              select new AccountHomeViewModel
              {
                totalPercent = (g.Count() / (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now) * 5.0)) * 100,
                totalPortionsPossible = (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now)+1)*5,
                totalPortionsAchieved = g.Count()
              }).First();
```

I now want to get some calculated values in my "select new AccountHomeViewModel".

So I've amended the linq to sql thus:

```
var resultTotal = (from fuf in db.fad_userFoods
              join fu in db.fad_user on fuf.userID equals fu.userID
              join ff in db.fad_food on fuf.foodID equals ff.foodID 
              where fuf.userID == thisGuid && fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
              group fuf.userID by new {fu.dateJoined, fuf.quantityAmount, ff.portionSize} into g
              select new AccountHomeViewModel
              {
                totalPercent = (g.Count() / (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now) * 5.0)) * 100,
                totalPortionsPossible = (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now)+1)*5,
                totalPortionsAchieved = g.Count(),
                calcValue = g.Sum(g.Key.quantityAmount)/g.Sum(g.Key.portionSize)
              }).First();
```

But I get an intellisense error in Visual Studio 2015 on both g.Sum parts saying:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'decimal?' to 'System.Func<System.Guid?, int>'
```

So I can see it's because I'm grouping by fuf.userID which is a GUID. But why is that affecting my SUM but not my COUNT?

I know it's my lack of understanding (this is my first MVC application and linq-to-sql) but where should I be looking to rectify this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only bringing back `fuf.userID` from your `group by` whilst also summing a property you are grouping by. Thus any attempt to access the decimal `quantityAmount` within an aggregate function in your `select` is going to fail. Try:

```
var resultTotal = (from fuf in db.fad_userFoods
          join fu in db.fad_user on fuf.userID equals fu.userID
          join ff in db.fad_food on fuf.foodID equals ff.foodID 
          where fuf.userID == thisGuid && fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
          group new {fuf.userID, fuf.quantityAmount, ff.portionSize} by new {fu.dateJoined} into g
          select new AccountHomeViewModel
          {
            totalPercent = (g.Count() / (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now) * 5.0)) * 100,
            totalPortionsPossible = (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now)+1)*5,
            totalPortionsAchieved = g.Count(),
            calcValue = g.Sum(q => q.quantityAmount)/g.Sum(q => q.portionSize)
          }).First();
```

This is the LINQ which should result in the T-SQL you require (as per comments below):

```
var resultTotal = (from fap in db.fad_user_physician
          join fu in db.fad_user on fup.userID equals fu.userID
          join fuf in db.fad_userFoods on fu.userID equals fuf.userID
          join ff in db.fad_food on fuf.foodID equals ff.foodID 
          where fup.physicianID == thisGuid && fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
          group new {fuf.quantityAmount, ff.portionSize, ff.alwaysOnePortion} by new {fuf.userId, fu.dateJoined} into g
          select new AccountHomeViewModel
          {
            totalPercent = (g.Count() / (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now) * 5.0)) * 100,
            calcValue = g.Sum(q => q.alwaysOnePortion == true ? 1: q.quantityAmount/q.portionSize)
          }).First();
```

Comment: Thanks strickt01. I have a lot to learn. The intellisense is now complainig about the Item in the calcValue expression. 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: DateTime? dateJoined>, <anonymous type: Guid? userID, decimal? quantityAmount, decimal? portionSize>>' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: DateTime? dateJoined>, <anonymous type: Guid? userID, decimal? quantityAmount, decimal? portionSize>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I normally reference the groupby using g.Key.xyz but quantityAmount and portionSize are no longer there to reference.

Comment: Sorry, had the syntax slightly wrong. Now corrected.

Comment: It worked but now I think my logic is incorrect and I'm not sure link-to-sql can do what I want.Basically I have a list of portions eaten and I need to compare that against the recommended portions.e.g.recommended portion for a banana is 1 but I eat 2 therefore I've eaten 2 portions that day.And I then need to add all those portions up.At the moment I'm just bringing back 1 portion for that scenario as I'm simply using quantityAmount >= portionSize.So my logic for calcValue is incorrect.If it was TSQL I'd just use cursors on the base list I obtained.But want to stick to linq-to-sql.Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify:Food items a,b,c,d. Portion size is 1,1,1,1. QuantityAmount is  1,1,1,2. Currenly I'm getting portions eaten as 4 (quantityAmount >= portionSize) but I need it to be 5 as I've eaten 2 lots of food item d. But only where that quantityAmount >= portionSize is fulfilled

Comment: I think there are quite a few things you need to work out: are you sure you want to be grouping by date joined rather than user for starters? Even if so, if you want `totalPortionsAchieved` to contain the total eaten then you need that to be `g.Sum(q => q.quantityAmount)`. `totalPortionsPossible ` is trickier - what logic are you trying to apply here (what is the 5.0 multiplier)?

Comment: This TSQL brings back a list of items which when added up gives me the correct number: `code`select ff.foodid,SUM(case ff.alwaysOnePortion when 1 then 1 else fuf.quantityAmount/ff.portionSize end) from fad_userFoods fuf inner join fad_food ff on ff.foodID = fuf.foodID
where fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
group by ff.foodid

Comment: Basically it's a medical app based around 5 a day  healthy eating. So the totalportions possible are the days since they've joined multiplied by 5 (5 portions a day).I then compare this against the number they've actually consumed to work out a percentage.As stated in my OP, my original linq-to-sql was working ok but I was having trouble extending that to work out this extra calculation

Comment: I had help with the original link-to-sql and that is what they suggested I do as I needed to have the dateJoined as something I could reference.So I had to group by it.

Comment: Don't spend too much time on this as I think it's beyond linq-to-sql from what I can see. It might be easier to set up a stored procedure and just call that. I'm in known territory then!! Just hate giving up on new stuff I'm learning but sometimes you have to know when to move on

Comment: This is the TSQL which works:`code`select fuf.userid,((CAST(COUNT(fuf.userid)AS DECIMAL(6,2))/(DATEDIFF(dd,fu.dateJoined,GETDATE())*5))*100) AS 'percent',
SUM(case ff.alwaysOnePortion when 1 then 1 else fuf.quantityAmount/ff.portionSize end)
from fad_user_physician fup
inner join fad_user fu on fu.userID = fup.userID
inner join fad_userFoods fuf on fuf.userID = fu.userID
inner join fad_food ff on ff.foodID = fuf.FoodID
where fup.physicianID = '5C46F531-FF64-4254-8072-F291627ABD3D'
AND fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
group by fuf.userID,fu.dateJoined

Comment: Look at it like this: the items in the `by` object in LINQ should contain the columns that you would `GROUP BY` in SQL. The `group` object should contain those columns that in T-SQL you would apply aggregate functions to in the `SELECT`. Then in your LINQ `select` you can perform aggregate functions to the properties of the object in `group` (using lambdas as above) whilst the object properties in the `by` should not be contained in aggregates.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some LINQ that should get the T-SQL you require although I'm working blind here so there may be syntactical issues...

Comment: Appreciate your time on this,especially working in the dark. q.alwaysOnePortion is givng an intellisense error saying `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: I'd assumed a bool rather than nullable bool. Use explicit `q.alwaysOnePortion == true` - answer edited accordingly.

Comment: That's because of the `First()`. Is the guid being passed in valid? Use `FirstOrDefault()` to avoid this - in which case the object returned will be `null`. Do a SQL Profiler trace - is the query correct? If so, please accept my amended answer as I think I ought to do some work of my own now...!

Comment: Yes guid is correct. Only bit I added was the new calcvalue. If I remove it then the query works but without the obvious calculation I need. Appreciate your time on this. Been invaluable in giving me guidance on link-to-sql and a great reference point to learn more. I'm going to use my SP for now and then come back to this. As I can't accept both answers as correct, Stack Exchange have said I should reward you and the other contributor by upvoting all your comments as these are worth 10 points each. As opposed to just 1 of you getting the 15 points. Unsure how else to be fair to both of you.

Comment: Bear in mind that I have changed the guid check from `fuf.userID == thisGuid` to `fup.physicianID == thisGuid` as per your T-SQL provided. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me! Fresh set of eyes today and yes I can see that fad_physician is irrelevant to my logic. So I've stripped that out and used fad_user as the primary table. So data is now coming back but I'm still getting the number of portions returned hitting the fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize. Which works out to be 50 so that's correct. BUT. It's ignoring those records where there are multi-portions.
i.e. portionSize is 1 quantityAmount is 2
Current linq-to-sql is bringing me back 1 portion when I need it to bring back 2, then SUM it all up.

Comment: fyi-tsql now reads:`select fu.userid,((CAST(COUNT(fu.userid)AS DECIMAL(6,2))/((DATEDIFF(dd,fu.dateJoined,GETDATE())+1)*5))*100) AS 'percent',
  SUM(case ff.alwaysOnePortion when 1 then 1 else fuf.quantityAmount/ff.portionSize end) AS 'portionsAchieved',
  ((DATEDIFF(dd,fu.dateJoined,GETDATE())+1)*5) AS 'totalPosPortions'
  from fad_user fu
  inner join fad_userFoods fuf on fuf.userID = fu.userID
  inner join fad_food ff on ff.foodID = fuf.FoodID
  where fu.userID = @userID
  AND fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
  group by fu.userID,fu.dateJoined`

Comment: Stack Exchange mods have suggested I set up a new question with your latest solution as a starting point as thisd question isn't deemed helpful now.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using .

```
   var resultTotal = (from fuf in db.fad_userFoods
      join fu in db.fad_user on fuf.userID equals fu.userID
      join ff in db.fad_food on fuf.foodID equals ff.foodID 
      where fuf.userID == thisGuid && fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize
      group new {Uid=fuf.userID,Qa=fuf.quantityAmount,Ps=ff.portionSize} by new {fu.dateJoined} into g
      select new AccountHomeViewModel
      {
        totalPercent = (g.Count() / (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now) * 5.0)) * 100,
        totalPortionsPossible = (DbFunctions.DiffDays(g.Key.dateJoined, DateTime.Now)+1)*5,
        totalPortionsAchieved = g.Count(),
        calcValue = g.Select(d=>d.Qa).Sum()/g.Select(d=>d.Ps).Sum()
      }).First();
```

**edit**
try changing `calcValue` by

```
    calcValue = g.Select(d=>d.Qa).Sum()/g.Select(d=>(d.Qa>d.Ps?d.Qa:d.Ps)).Sum()
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: yo can do it by linq . let me update answer and then check it works or not.

Comment: This is the TSQL which works:`code`select fuf.userid,((CAST(COUNT(fuf.userid)AS DECIMAL(6,2))/(DATEDIFF(dd,fu.dateJoined,GETDATE())*5))*100) AS 'percent', SUM(case ff.alwaysOnePortion when 1 then 1 else fuf.quantityAmount/ff.portionSize end) from fad_user_physician fup inner join fad_user fu on fu.userID = fup.userID inner join fad_userFoods fuf on fuf.userID = fu.userID inner join fad_food ff on ff.foodID = fuf.FoodID where fup.physicianID = '5C46F531-FF64-4254-8072-F291627ABD3D' AND fuf.quantityAmount >= ff.portionSize group by fuf.userID,fu.dateJoined

Comment: Thanks Viplock but still brings back the wrong numbers for calcValue.I think I'll just use the stored procedure.As much as I hate pulling back from learning new stuff, I think this is a case of running before I'm walking!!TSQL is known territory for me!

Comment: what its returning and what you want ?

Comment: Basically it's a medical app based around 5 a day healthy eating. So the totalportions possible are the days since they've joined multiplied by 5 (5 portions a day).I then compare this against the number they've actually consumed to work out a percentage.As stated in my OP, my original linq-to-sql was working ok but I was having trouble extending that to work out this extra calculation

Comment: Tried your edited calcValue expression but still the wrong numbers. It's been a great lesson in linq-to-sql and I've learned a lot so thanks for that. But I don't think linq-to-sql can handle this so I'm going to call the Stored Procedure which I know works. Thanks again.